# Perform function in django after rendering page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like to know if there is how I execute a command after rendering the Django page.

I have a system where I set the telephony training variable to False and run a command line with subprocess.Popen and I have to wait for the command to finish with .communicate () and say that the telephony training variable is True, but the command takes about 15 minutes to execute, so I would like to render the page as soon as the command is executed. My code is as follows:

```
def GerarTreinoTelefonia(request):
    global treinamentotelefonia
    if treinamentotelefonia == False:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            treinamentotelefonia = True
            treinotelefonia = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('python -m rasa_nlu.train -c chatbot/config/config_nlu.yml --data chatbot/dados/ilhas/telefonia/ -o /code/chatbot/models/telefonia --fixed_model_name nlu --project current --verbose'))
            return render(request, 'website/PainelGerenciamento.html')
            treinotelefonia.communicate()
            treinamentotelefonia = False
```

Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: If you absolutely need it when the page has been rendered, then put in an AJAX call in your page?

Comment: Having a global variable and setting it during a request here is almost certainly a bad idea in terms of thread safety (aside from generally being inadvisable in terms of readability and maintainability).